# Push values from one sheet to another?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013, vba

I have one "Main sheet" where I want to view certain key values but I also want to add more/new data to the "Data sheet" through an update field with the press of a button. The cell I want to update is dynamic but I have the cell address in cell S4.

Example:

If I would want a new comment for "Tyrion Lannister" I would want to:

1. Write the full name in the "name" field (D3), which gives me the row in the "Data sheet"
2. Select the field i want to update though a data validation list (Q4), gives me the column in the "Data sheet".
3. Type the new comment in cell P5
4. Click on an update button
5. If possible I would also want to confirm all updates so no mistakes are made.

SOLVED 
by using this code:

```
Sub Test1()

x = Range("rad")
y = Range("kolumn")
Z = Range("update")

Sheets("Data").Cells(x, y) = Z

End Sub
```

Comment: Your samples make no sense. An Update is typically used to change fields based on a unique identifier or many fields within a group. An Insert is to create new records. Surely the *first name* is not unique but you would want to change something for everyone with a first name of *Bob*. Redated sample data is very wise but there comes a point where it simply makes no sense.

Comment: I don't like to use the word impossible, but I think this might be without any VBA. As Jeeped mentioned, you'd need a unique identifier to find the person you need to edit, unless there are no duplicated names? A data validation list would be possible to implement. I'd suggest looking into the VBA, then deciding if you want to make a form to input the data, or use input boxes or message boxes. This will then help you to build the structure as to how you can tackle this problem.

Comment: @Shauno_88 Thank you for taking your time to answer

Comment: If this is solved then you can Answer your own question.

Comment: @Davesexcel Didn't know that i could do that, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED 
using this code:

```
Sub Test1()

x = Range("rad")
y = Range("kolumn")
Z = Range("update")

Sheets("Data").Cells(x, y) = Z

End Sub
```